# how to get the 12 hour date from DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

when i get the DateTime.Hour property, i always get the 24 hour time (so 6PM would give me 18).

how do i get the "12 hour" time so 6PM just gives me 6.

i obviously can do the check myself but i assume there is a built in function for this.

Comment: you could just ask him, or do you mean DateTim*e*?

Comment: If you do this though, how can you compare between morning and night hours?

Comment: i dont need to for this one control  . . . as there are seperate text boxes for "Hour" "Min" "AM/PM".  i am going to move this to a calendar control to make it simpler as this is all inherited code

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about:

```
DateTime.Hour % 12
```

That will give 0-11 of course... do you want 1-12? If so:

```
((DateTime.Hour + 11) % 12) + 1
```

I don't *think* there's anything simpler built in...

Answer (score 9):

DateTime.Now.ToString("hh");   --> Using this you will get "06" for 18h.

Comment: This is the simplest answer imo.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any built in method, but you can always add an extension method to accomplish this.

Of course, you could always replace the code with the way you want to accomplish it.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static int GetTwelveCycleHour(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        if (dateTime.Hour > 12)
        {
            return dateTime.Hour - 12;
        }

        return dateTime.Hour;
    }
}
```

Comment: I realized that after I posted my answer, so I added the comment "Of course, you could always replace the code with the way you want to accomplish it." My main point was that this question to me sounds like a good candidate for an extension method.

Comment: I didn't want to just rip off Jon Skeet's answer into my own, so I only added the comment and didn't change the code.

Answer (score 2):

What about simply:

```
public static int GetTwelveCycleHour(this DateTime dateTime)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(dateTime.ToString("h"));
}
```

Comment: Formatting and parsing?  This will do the trick, but is unnecessarily wasteful of CPU cycles.  Save formatting for displaying output, and parsing for handling user input.  You're much better off with Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: Not sure about the C# version you are using but in C#5 this throws an invalid format exception. it should be ToString("%h");

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in function, mainly because you shouldn't need it:

- If you're doing this for output to the user, look at using a format string.
- If you're doing this for a calculation, you can subtract datetimes or add timespans directly.

Outside of this, the math calculation is simple enough and already available in other answers here.

Comment: i am doing hour comparisons compared to an integer i am getting from another data source (which obviously only comes in 12 hour time)

Comment: Shouldn't you convert that other source to a datetime?  Blindly comparing 12hour times is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the most convenient answer was submitted by Jon Skeet.  The below is the same but converted to Visual Basic.  I like things to be super easy.  It took me a few to figure out the C# to Visual Basic Conversion.  I included some 'extra' stuff as well.  Hope this saves someone else time.

**Visual Basic**

```
(((DateTime.Now().Hour + 11) Mod 12) + 1)
```

**Extra**

```
Dim stringDate = DateTime.Now().Year &
                 DateTime.Now().Month.ToString("00") &
                 DateTime.Now().Day.ToString("00") & "_" &
                 (((DateTime.Now().Hour + 11) Mod 12) + 1).ToString("00") &
                 DateTime.Now().Minute.ToString("00")
```

The `ToString("00")` forces each Month/Day/Hour/Minute to always be represented by two digits.

Year = `2019`

Month: April 4 = `04`

Day: 3 = `03`

Hour: 10 = `10`

5 Minutes = `05`

stringDate = `201904031005`

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("12/12/2022 20:20:00 PM");
    var hour = date.Hour;
    var dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime((date.ToShortDateString() + " " + hour + ":00:00"));
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime); // 12/12/2022 8:00:00 PM
    Console.WriteLine(hour); // 20
```